# Creating thematic map where individual points are basically grid in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, heat-map, grids-graticules, thematic-map

I want to plot a heat map which shows the different usage in different areas. But the thing is, in my original dataset, the data got truncated, which means that each point represents a small area rather than a certain point of latitude and longitude. For example,

```
(14.21, 55.38)-> represents a square of place for (14.21XXXXXX,55.38XXXXXX)
```

I have searched the tutorial file and tried, but I can only get my points with different shapes and darkness, rather than making them continuously showed in a map. I am new to GIS and MapInfo.

Can you give me some ideas of how to transfer my points to grids, or how to directly use the points to create heatmap which is not displayed discretely?

A snapshot of my picture:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend that you try to go back to your original dataset and see if you are able to get the full accuracy. Also note that if you look at your values in MapInfo Pro you might only see some of the decimals. Try to click on a record in the browser and see if more decimals appear

Comment: No, because it is intentionally truncated for the efficiency. Which means, one row actually represents an area rather than a point. But in MapInfo, when I loaded my file, I feel it would recognize my record as points.

Comment: So you are saying that you want these points to be displayed as squares? Maybe if you could show how your points look in a map we could better understand what you are trying to do. Once you have the created points for all your records you can show them in a map window. From this you can then either create a grid using Map > Add Theme, Grid. Or I can show you how to convert your points into squares of a certain size.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have uploaded a snapshot of my file. I think the second method you have proposed might work. Basically, each point represents an area, and we hope the grid we build (or square) can be colored based on the value of the points.

Comment: Actually, I think you'd get the best result by gridding the data using the Grid Theme. You can see how int he description below. Just ignore the last part about the tool All2Pnts as you already have points for your data.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this with **Map\Create Thematic Map...** (or just press F9)
Choose "*Grid*" as a type of thematic map and select appropriate profile.

In next 3 dialog's you can modify all settings from value field to color.

[image]

With default profile and selected point layer final result is MapInfo grid file.

[image]

To transfer your object to points you could use [all2pts.mbx](http://www.mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=10&sobi2Id=242&Itemid=53) a free MapBasic tool (*"Utility to convert a table of pline or region objects to points. You might use this for gridding applications that require points instead of contours or elevation regions"*).

Comment: I have tried a little bit with the MapBasic program, but the thing is, my original type is "point" (actually it is a grid), and I don't think all2pts can transfer my original type to exact points since it will return to an error saying "pts.mb:156 Unable to create table definition file"